# How can I set to HTML Tags to Normal View in Android?

Tags: android, html

I have like this html blog

```
<head>
<style>
<!--.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family:Tahoma
}
--></style></head>
<body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>
text<div>write</div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

text and write are the results. This Html tags must shown as

```
-----------
text write |
-----------
```

How can I do that in Android?

Answer (score 0):

seems to me this should be easy to achieve from the css:

```
div.ltr div
{
 display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand. Am I search this code "css to normal view"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to present texts in your app.

Comment: I must use ListView to show them like in this example "text write". But they are writing with these tags

Comment: You actually use TextViews to show texts as list Items inside ListView. So anyhow your last resort is still TextViews

Comment: I understand but what I need to do dont show these code "<!--.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family:Tahoma
}
-->" in textview

Answer (score 0):

use html in `textview`or `button` as following

```
String htmltext = "<html><body>/*... html body here...*/</body></html>";

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmltext));
```

if you want to use css style or javascript use `webview` like

`webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmltext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: With this code sample, the app shows <!--.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family:Tahoma
}
--> text write

Comment: But I just want to write "text write" What should I do?

Comment: HTML Tags Supported By TextView are given at [this link](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) . style tag is not suported.

Comment: I understand but what I need to do dont show these code "<!--.hmmessage P { margin:0px; padding:0px } body.hmmessage { font-size: 10pt; font-family:Tahoma } -->" in textview

Comment: if you want to use css style use webview like `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmltext, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`